# Next.js permission denied to package.json file after docker compose up

Tags: docker, next.js, permissions, permission-denied, file-access

Starting with `docker compose up` I'm facing an error below:

```
frontend  | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
frontend  | info  - Loaded env from /app/.env.local
frontend  | [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/.next/package.json'] {
frontend  |   errno: -13,
frontend  |   code: 'EACCES',
frontend  |   syscall: 'open',
frontend  |   path: '/app/.next/package.json'
frontend  | }
frontend exited with code 1
```

Can't find any solution to this. I see this error even with 777 permissions for this file.

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
ARG BASE=node:16.17.1

# install deps
FROM ${BASE} AS project_name_frontend_dev

USER root
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

# for dev purpose
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I've tried to modify file/folder permissions, rebuild container and modify USER & COPY data in Dockerfile.dev.

**EDIT:**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  front:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      args:
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONT_HOST: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONT_HOST}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONT_BASE: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONT_BASE}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDIA_PATH: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDIA_PATH}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_APP_ID: ${NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_APP_ID}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_CHAT_HOST: ${ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_CHAT_HOST}
        ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_CHAT_BASE: ${ARG_NEXT_PUBLIC_CHAT_BASE}

    networks:
      - project_net_name
    extra_hosts:
      - "api.project_name.local:ip-address"

networks:
  project_net_name:
    external: true
```

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
services:
  front:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      target: project_name_frontend_dev
    networks:
      - project_net_name
    extra_hosts:
      - "api.project_name.local:ip-address"
    environment:
      NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
```

Comment: How are you running the container?  Are you overwriting the container's `app` directory with a bind mount (in which case nothing in the Dockerfile has an effect)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I've attached docker-compose.yml files.

Comment: It's weird case, because I'm running same app with same config (only different docker network address) and everything is fine.

Comment: Temporary ducktaped, I've replaced CMD with "CMD bash && npm run dev ; chmod 777 -R /app/.next ; npm run dev". But I'm aware that this is not the best practice.